# How do i slide a new animate to a page with other elements moving to make space for it?

Tags: html, css

I want to fade+move an hidden element ( display:none ) inside the page between certain elements and i want the other elements to animate their way to their new position.
Now when i turn the new element to "display:initial" the new available place will just pop up.

Comment: What is your code??? do you have a jsfiddle???

Answer (score 0):

try using visibility:hidden; instead of display:none; and then use css3 animations to fade in and move your other elements when you are using visibility then also use opacity:0 on the fading element.[Link to css3 animations](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)

```
.fade{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   background-color:red;
   float:left;
   opacity:1;
   -webkit-animation: fade 0.5s linear  infinite alternate;
}

.move{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   background-color:green;
   margin-left:100px;
   float:left;
   -webkit-animation: move 0.5s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes move {
   from {margin-left:0;}
   to {margin-left:100px;}
}

@keyframes fade {
   from {opacity:0;}
   to {opacity:1;}
}
```

[Example here](http://codepen.io/o0nico0o/pen/WvGEdP)

Comment: Thanks! I will try that and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I had to use display and not visibility because i needed it to not block clickable elements while it wasn't shown and only display non does that, so i just added one more division that will hold it all and animated it's height so the area will be opened smoothly.